# Text search on many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, subquery, many-to-many

I have three tables: `cars`, `colours`, and `cars_has_colours`, the first two of which have a many-to-many relationship.

I'd like to search `cars`, ideally using MATCH and AGAINST. This is very simple to achieve if I wanted to search `cars.name`.

I'd like to search `colours` with MATCH and AGAINST, if possible. The reason for this is so that the result of MATCH on colours can be added to the result of MATCH on names etc.

So, for example, if I searched for "blue" I would like to see any cars that are "Sky Blue" or "Navy Blue".

Ideally I would like to use text search and be able to get some kind of relevancy score, as opposed to using WHERE/IN, so that when searching for "blue", "Sky Blue" and "Navy Blue" coloured cars are returned, but so would a car named "bluebird" (even though it may not necessarily have a relationship with "blue" in `colours`)

I've tried GROUP_CONCAT on a subquery, which gives me a string with all the colours in, however I can't use that as an argument in MATCH (bizarrely, the error I get tells me that I have an invalid argument in AGAINST, even though I'm just putting a string literal in as per the docs)

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT c.*, cl.colour, 
       (MATCH (cl.colour AGAINST ('blue') + MATCH(c.name) AGAINST ('blue')) AS score
FROM cars AS c
LEFT JOIN cars_has_colours AS cc ON cc.car_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN colours AS cl ON cc.colour_id = cl.id AND MATCH(cl.colour) AGAINST ('blue')
WHERE MATCH (c.name) AGAINST ('blue') OR cl.id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Comment: thanks, that's certainly how you do it - although for future readers it should be noted that you cannot MATCH across two different tables, and that you should use LEFT JOIN to match cars which have blue in the name but not in their colours

Comment: Thanks, I think this update should accomodate that correction.